How to sort an array of objects from least to greatest, based on the value of a specified attribute
I'm creating a tournament bracket and the team data is stored in an array like this:
tourneyTeamsCondensed = {
"name": "Team1","wins": "2","losses": "4",
"name": "Team2","wins": "3","losses": "3",
"name": "Team3","wins": "3","losses": "4",
"name": "Team4","wins": "4","losses": "1"};

For the standings, I'd like to store them in a new array, sorted by highest "wins" to lowest, then sorting by lowest to highest "losses" as a tiebreaker. The result should like this:
standingsTeams = {
"name": "Team4","wins": "4","losses": "1",
"name": "Team2","wins": "3","losses": "3",
"name": "Team3","wins": "3","losses": "4",
"name": "Team1","wins": "2","losses": "4"};

How can I accomplish this?
Here's what I tried:

        // Sorting tourneyTeamsCondensed from most wins to least, outputting into standingsTeams

        for (var i = 0; i < tourneyTeamsCondensed.length; i++) {
            var insertCheck = false;
            for (var j = 0; j < standingsTeams.length; j++) {

                if (tourneyTeamsCondensed[i].wins > standingsTeams[j].wins ||
                    (tourneyTeamsCondensed[i].wins === standingsTeams[j].wins &&
                    tourneyTeamsCondensed[i].losses < standingsTeams[j].losses)) {
                    insertCheck = true;
                    standingsTeams.splice(j, 0, tourneyTeamsCondensed[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!insertCheck) {
                standingsTeams.push(tourneyTeamsCondensed[i]);
            }
        }

        console.log(standingsTeams)


I had this functionality working previously, but using tourneyTeams instead of tourneyTeamsCondensed. tourneyTeamsCondensed is tourneyTeams, but with wins and losses summed, based on a common "name" attribute. Aside from replacing instances of tourneyTeams with tourneyTeamsCondensed, I changed nothing.
Console logging tourneyTeamsCondensed shows that it's working as intended, so that shouldn't be the problem.
Console logging standingsTeams results in an empty array.

First of all, it is important to mention that the original format of your JSON data is not quite valid because all fields in that object are repeated multiple times. Probably, you wanted it to be an array of objects. If this is the case, you can sort objects in the array in the following way:


const tourneyTeamsCondensed = [
  { name: "Team1", wins: "2", losses: "4" },
  { name: "Team2", wins: "3", losses: "3" },
  { name: "Team3", wins: "3", losses: "4" },
  { name: "Team4", wins: "4", losses: "1" },
];

const result = tourneyTeamsCondensed.sort((a, b) => {
  const winsA = parseInt(a.wins);
  const winsB = parseInt(b.wins);
  if (winsA !== winsB) {
    return winsB - winsA;
  }
  const lossesA = parseInt(a.losses);
  const lossesB = parseInt(b.losses);
  return lossesA - lossesB;
});

console.log(result);



You can notice that since wins and losses are stored as strings in the initial JSON, I had to parse them during sorting. This is a quite bad approach from performance perspective and to address it, I would suggest to extract parsing into a separate step before sorting, like so:


const tourneyTeamsCondensed = [
  { name: "Team1", wins: "2", losses: "4" },
  { name: "Team2", wins: "3", losses: "3" },
  { name: "Team3", wins: "3", losses: "4" },
  { name: "Team4", wins: "4", losses: "1" },
];

const parsedData = tourneyTeamsCondensed.map(team => ({
  name: team.name,
  wins: parseInt(team.wins),
  losses: parseInt(team.losses)
}));

const result = parsedData.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.wins !== b.wins) {
    return b.wins - a.wins;
  }
  return a.losses - b.losses;
});

console.log(result);



Now sorting looks nice and tidy :)
Please let me know if this helps.

@Ozan Awesome! Would you mind marking my answer as correct if it was helpful? Thanks!


const tourneyTeamsCondensed = [
  { name: "Team1", wins: "2", losses: "4" },
  { name: "Team2", wins: "3", losses: "3" },
  { name: "Team3", wins: "3", losses: "4" },
  { name: "Team4", wins: "4", losses: "1" },
];

let result = tourneyTeamsCondensed.sort((a,b) => {
    if(a.wins > b.wins){
        return -1
    } else{
        return 1
    }
});
console.log(result)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.



let teams = [
  { name: "Team1", wins: "2", losses: "4" },
  { name: "Team2", wins: "3", losses: "3" },
  { name: "Team3", wins: "3", losses: "4" },
  { name: "Team4", wins: "4", losses: "1" },
];

console.log(teams.sort((a,b) => b.wins.localeCompare(a.wins)))



// localeCompare works only for Strings
